# Help in the proof of the Laurent series theorem

Tags: complex-analysis, proof-explanation, laurent-series

I'm reading [Conway's complex analysis book](https://psm73.files.wordpress.com/2009/03/conway.pdf) and on page 107 he proved the following theorem:

[image]

I didn't understand this part of the proof:

[image]
[image]
[image]

Why $f(z)=\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{\gamma} \frac{f(w)}{w-z}dw$?

What the winding numbers $n(\gamma_2,z)$ and $n(\gamma_1,z)$ have to do with everything?

Comment: Read Cauchy Integral Formula: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy's_integral_formula , and then google winding number: it is needed for the complete, more formal Cauchy Integral Theorem and Formula.

Answer (score 2):

On page 92 he stated the following theorem:

[image]

Now it suffices to use this corollary to have the hypothesis of this theorem on page 84:

[image]